# Why does my dropdown stop working if I use code with errors?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

This drop down code is working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.owl-wrapper').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true,
    autoPlay: 100,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:2
        },
        1000:{
            items:3
        }
    }
})
```

This drop down code is not working: Why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.owl-wrapper').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true,
    autoPlay: 100,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:
        },
        600:{
            items:2
        },
        1000:{
            items:3
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to give the value to items in your second example. You need to give it a value as you have given in your first example.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('.owl-wrapper').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true,
    autoPlay: 100,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:2
        },
        1000:{
            items:3
        }
    }
});
```

You can always check [here](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#how-to) to know how to use the owlCarousel.